# How to pull out negative signs through subscripted variables while displaying output in traditional form?

Tags: output-formatting, traditional-form, subscript

I am trying to get an expression to display correctly in `TraditionalForm`, with the negative sign in front of other symbols:

```
-Conjugate[Subscript["ϵ", "k"]] Subscript["Δ", "k"] // TraditionalForm //TeXForm
```

> $\Delta _{\text{k}} \left(-\left(\epsilon _{\text{k}}\right){}^*\right)$

As you can see, the negative sign appears between the delta and epsilon, instead of appearing in front of both. It works as I expect if the delta is not subscripted.

```
-Conjugate[Subscript["ϵ", "k"]] "Δ" // TraditionalForm //TeXForm
```

> $-\Delta  \left(\epsilon _{\text{k}}\right){}^*$

Is there a way to force the negative sign to appear before the other symbols, even when using subscripted variables?

Answer (score 2):

`HoldForm` command can prevent reshuffling of terms.

For example:

```
HoldForm[-Conjugate[Subscript["\[Epsilon]", "k"]] Subscript["\[CapitalDelta]", "k"]] // TraditionalForm
```

will result in:

$-(\epsilon_k)^* \Delta_k$

Answer (score 0):

I think this probably should be considered a bug, but support may not agree. At any rate, if you don't mind mucking about with internal functions, you can fix this with the following patch:

```
TraditionalFormDump`ordtimes[Lb_, Lconst_] /; !TrueQ@$Fix := Block[{$Fix=True},
    If[negativeRowBox[Lb[[1]]],
        Prepend[1 + TraditionalFormDump`ordtimes[Rest @ Lb, Lconst], 1],
        TraditionalFormDump`ordtimes[Lb, Lconst]
    ]
]

negativeRowBox[{" ", rb_[{"-",__}]}] := StringStartsQ[SymbolName[rb], "myRowBox$"]
negativeRowBox[_] = False;
```

Then:

```
-Conjugate[Subscript["ϵ","k"]] Subscript["Δ","k"] //TraditionalForm //TeXForm
```

> $-\left(\epsilon _{\text{k}}\right){}^* \Delta _{\text{k}}$

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
- Conjugate[Subscript["ϵ", "k"]] Subscript["Δ", "k"] /. 
       Times[a_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ, b__] :> HoldForm[a Times[b]] // 
    TraditionalForm // TeXForm
```

> $-\Delta _{\text{k}} \left(\epsilon _{\text{k}}\right){}^*$

Comment: This doesn't work so well with more multiplicands, e.g., `-Conjugate[Subscript["ϵ", "k"]] Subscript["Δ", "k"] Subscript[x, k]`